# Pattern match in Erlang

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

I am trying to learn some Erlang while I got stuck on these several Erlang pattern matching problems.
Given the module here:

```erlang
-module(p1).
-export([f2/1]).

f2([A1, A2 | A1]) -> {A2, A1};
f2([A, true | B]) -> {A, B};
f2([A1, A2 | _]) -> {A1,A2}; 
f2([_|B]) -> [B];
f2([A]) -> {A}; 
f2(_) -> nothing_matched.
```

and when I execute `p1:f2([x])`, I received an empty list which is `[]`. I thought it matches the 5th clause? Is that a literal can also be an atom?

When I execute `p1:f2([[a],[b], a])`, the result is `([b], [a])` which means it matches the first clause. However I think [a] and a are not the same thing? One is a list but the other is a literal?

Also when I execute `p1:f2([2, 7 div 3 > 2 | [5,3]])` it evaluates to `(2, false)`. I mean why `7 div 3 > 2` gets to be false? In other language such as C or Java Yeah I know `7 div 3 == 2` so it makes this statement false. But is it the same in Erlang? Because I just tried it on shell and it gives me `2.3333333..` which is larger than `2` so it will make this statement true. Can someone gives an explaination?

Comment: In shell you probably typed 7 / 3 which is floating point division. `div` and `rem` applies to and returns integers only.

Comment: @ŁukaszPtaszyński yes you are right! I really thought `/` operation does the same thing as `div` but it seems like there is certainly a difference between the number types!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because `[x]` is equal to `[x|[]]` so it matches `f2([_|B]) -> [B];`. As you can see `B=[]` inn your case.

I think you didn't write what you want to do. in the expression `[A|B]`, A is the first element of the list, while B is the rest of the list (so it is a list). That means that `[1,2,1]` will not match `[A1, A2 | A1]`; but `[[1],2,1]` or `[[a,b],1,a,b]` will.

Comment: well actually I am just trying to do some Erlang exercise to get to know pattern match more. So these are some examples, they don't really aim for something :)

Answer (score 2):

First,  `7 div 3` is 2. And 2 is not greater than 2, it's equal.

Secondly, `[x, y] = [x | [y] ]`, because the right (or *rest*) part is always a list. That's why you get in the first clause.